# Match first instance of digit by Regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex and need to extract just the 'Chr' number by reading an entry at a time.

For example, for the following data:

```
Chr6_clust92082
Chr7_clust13
Chr7_clust256
Chr7_clust3678
Chr7_clust42
Chr7_clust5
Chr7_clust130538
```

The first entry should return '6' because it is right after 'Chr' and before '_'. Please suggest the specific regex for it.

Comment: Is that number only one digit, or can it be multiple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following, it will look even if there are more than one digits -

```
re.findall(r'^Chr([\d]+)_', 'Chr6_clust92082')[0]
```

Comment: No need to use a character class. `\d+` can stand well on its own.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to match many times it's best to compile the pattern:

```
c = re.compile('Chr(\d)_')
```

and if you can have chr-numbers larger than 9 it should be:

```
c = re.compile('Chr(\d*)_')
```

then you'd do:

```
t = 'Chr6_clust92082'
n = int(re.match(c, t).groups()[0])
```

just changing the t for each iteration of course.

Though you asked for regexp, since the pattern is so simple it might be worth using:

```
n = int(t.split("_",1)[0][3:])
```

I timed that one for 1110000 strings (don't ask me why) of your pattern and it took 8.8 seconds, while the regex version took 21.4 seconds.

Comment: 8.8 Seconds really....I thought regex will be fast and thats why wanted to use it...anyways thanks

Comment: I might not have done the most efficient regex there is, but I would guess that it has to do with that it creates a new object for each string it parses. And creating objects takes some time, while the list that is made from the split is probably much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this regular expression:

```
re.match('Chr(\d+)_.*','Chr6_clust92082')
```

Comment: I think you want a period before that asterisk: `_.*` instead of `_*`.

Comment: You are making an assumption here, that number has only one digit.

Comment: I agree with both of you, I just took the samples as assumption but it would be a better answer for the OP. Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the type of Question which is welcome on stackoverflow. No one will do your work. 
The regex you need is really easy to find.

I suggest you this online tool: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

It helps a lot finding Regular Expressions

Comment: This is not the type of answer which is welcome on StackOverflow either (well, it isn't an answer at all). You should post this as a comment, maybe.